# How can I get the regular expression correct?

Tags: c#, regex

How can I write just one expression to represent the following cases?
These Matrix Blocks all have similar structures, with the eception of different lines inside, varying all the way.

```
    Matrix "mat-31" SPRING 3 1 {
        0.000000 43.039398 0.000001 -0.000000
    }

    Matrix "mat-48" SPRING 3 2 {
        0.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
        3.495787 19.341287 0.234091 -23487819       
    }

    Matrix "mat-25" SPRING 3 4 {
        0.000000 12.855400 -0.000001 -10.844367
        3.234897 6.123478 23.239048 -13.787821
        6.234897 8.123721 23.239048 -18.342451
        1.234897 6.123478 23.239048 -19.453821

    }
    Matrix "mat-12" SPRING 3 3 {
        0.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
        7.232397 7.123478 8.239048 -1.453821
        3.889897 2.166474 -16.2443048 -9.453821
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see no reason to process this with regular expressions. Do you happen to have one?

Comment: What do you mean by "represent the following cases"? What does it have to do with a regular expression?

Comment: You will have to explain in more detail about what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to match one of these "Matrix ... }" blocks as a string?

Comment: ya, I am trying to match one of these "Matrix ...}" blocks as a string.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert: Are you serious?  That's a whole lot more work than just matching a regex.

Comment: Jeremy: He (I assume) means reading line by line, looking for tokens, and gathering data. It's really quite simple, and is far more clear then a regex, as well as handling more complex cases easier, and allowing for trivial gathering of sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Matrix\s+"[^"]*"\s+SPRING\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+{[^}]*}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Matrix\s+"[^"]+"\s+SPRING\s+\d\s+\d\s+\{(\s+-?\d+(\.\d+)?)+\s+}
```

Answer (score 1):

A pattern like this should work for matching a matrix:

```
Matrix "(.*?)" SPRING (\d+) (\d+) \{(?:(\s+-?\d+\.\d+){4})+\s+\}
```

Comment: You're not matching the spaces between the numbers in the body of the matrices.

Comment: @Jeremy: You are right, the starting parenthesis was on the wrong side of the leading space.

Comment: This still doesn't match the second example because the last number doesn't have a decimal point.